# SSIS package taking ages to edit components

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package that was working fine earlier today. In the past hour, it has started taking 2+ minutes to open a script component in the data flow for editing.

I have not changed anything significant so unsure what the issue is.

Package consists of:

- script task to obtain  xml feed from web service.
- Derived column shape.
- destination OLEDB connection to sql server.

I have tried the following so far, to no avail:

- on the script task set "validateExternalMetadata" to false.
- On the DataFlowTask set "DelayValidation" to true.
- For the project i have tried both 32 & 64 bit debugging.

Id appreciate any help as its making development almost impossible

Comment: I'd try closing and reopening Visual Studio (BIDS), and if that doesn't help, re-start your computer.